# JCR Versioning Operation Slows Down After a While

Tags: java, content-management-system, jackrabbit, jcr, sling

In my project, I use such the following code to release a version for a node:

```
VersionManager vm = ...;

Version v = vm.checkin([node path...]);

vm.checkout([node path...]);
```

And set a label for the version:

```
vm.getVersionHistory([node path...]).addVersionLabel(v.getName(), [version label: "edit", "create"], false);
```

It works fine, but after a while this operation slows down and takes a long time almost 3-4 min.

If I restart Sling it work well again.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: It would be useful if you could provide a stack trace / profiler dump of what goes on when the operation is slow. Also, what version of Jackrabbit are you using with Sling and have you made any changes in its configuration?